# how to start timer after button is clicked in class component using life cycle methods

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I wanted to start the timer when i clicked on start timer button but i am not bale to do this facing some error says bind property not able to read and also nothing is showing on dom.

```js
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import "../styles/App.css";
class Timer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { time: 0, x: 0, y: 0 };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    startTime = ()=>{
      this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState(prev=>{
          return {time : prev.time + 1}
        })
      }, 1000);
    }
    
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(timer)
  }

  render() {
    return(
    <>
    <span>Time :{this.state.time}</span>
    <button onClick={this.startTime.bind(this)}>Start Timer</button>
    </>
    )
  }
}

export default Timer;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to move the `startTime` function outside the `componentDidMount`, as you can see the below code. I hope this works.

```
import React from "react";
import "../styles/App.css";
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { time: 0, x: 0, y: 0 };
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timer)
  }
  
  startTime = ()=>{
      this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.setState(prev=>{
          return {time : prev.time + 1}
        })
      }, 1000);
    }
  render() {
    return(
    <>
    <span>Time :{this.state.time}</span>
    <button onClick={this.startTime.bind(this)}>Start Timer</button>
    </>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Ahmad Faraz not working says Compilation problem.

Comment: can you please paste the Compilation problem here.

Comment: Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: G:\Amir NS\React Projects\In Class\Timed-Golf---Adding-Dynamic-Styles-Setting-CSS-Classes-Dynamically-React-State---xcnl7j13r8sk\src\components\App.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (16:13):

Comment: _modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12241:14
    at Object.withTopicForbiddingContext (G:\Amir NS\React Projects\In Class\Timed-Golf---Adding-Dynamic-Styles-Setting-CSS-Classes-Dynamically-React-State---xcnl7j13r8sk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:11272:14)
    at Object.parseClassBody (G:\Amir NS\React Projects\In Class\Timed-Golf---Adding-Dynamic-Styles-Setting-CSS-Classes-Dynamically-React-State---xcnl7j13r8sk\node_modules\@babel\parser\lib\index.js:12218:10)
 @ ./src/index.js 3:0-35 4:50-53
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.

Comment: I have updated the answer. can you please check.